# If $f_n \to f$ pointwise and $f'_n \to g$ pointwise, does it follow that $f'=g$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I'm trying to solve the following problem (which seems to be the same as in [Derivative of a pointwise limit of a sequence of functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4628289/derivative-of-a-pointwise-limit-of-a-sequence-of-functions) but it does not have answers)

*If $f_n:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of continuously differentiable functions on $[a,b]$ that converges pointwise to a continuously differentiable function $f$ on $[a,b]$ and if the sequence $(f'_n)$ converges pointwise to a function $g$ on $[a,b]$, does it follow that $f'=g$?*

---

I know that if $(f'_n)$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ to a function $g$ then $g=f'$, but I'm not sure if that happens if $(f'_n)$ just converges pointwise. I'm having trouble finding a counterexample.

Comment: $f_n(x) = x^{n+1}/(n+1) \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ on $[0,1]$. But $f'_n(x) = x^n \to \delta_{\{1\}}(x)$